# When to use Guice's Just-in-time Bindings?

Tags: java, guice

I read [Guice's documentation on its Just-in-time Bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings) and it says nothing about when to use it. Also on [on their main GitHub page](https://github.com/google/guice) they say:

> Guice is not a kitchen sink. We justify each feature with at least three use cases.

I can't find a section where they would show me such use cases for their Just-in-time bindings.

Thank you.

P.S. I am sorry if I have made any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Google Guice didn’t provide use cases because this is the core feature of Guice. It seems to me that everything else is a feature on top of JIT bindings or a feature that fills a gap where you can’t use JIT bindings. That being said, I’m not on the Guice team, so I can’t really do anything more than speculate about what they were thinking.

Anyway, here are some use cases I came up with

1. You don’t have to write a lot of trivial bindings.
2. You can use Guice without writing modules.
3. You might need Guice to instantiate something from a library that was not built with Guice bindings or annotations.